# tcpdump to catch ICMP packets

Tags: linux, tcpdump

I'm using **tcpdump** to capture the traffic and I want to capture **ICMP** traffic from/to local host. So why `tcpdump -i lo` 
works but not `tcpdump host 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the [`tcpdump` man page](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html), you'll discover in the description of the `-i interface` option that, *"If unspecified, `tcpdump` searches the system interface list for the lowest numbered, configured up interface (excluding loopback) ..."*

This means the interface you're capturing on isn't the loopback interface, `lo` but some other interface, which surely won't match any packets using a capture filter of `host 127.0.0.1`.

Incidentally, you can find out which interface `tcpdump` will specifically capture on if the interface isn't specified by running `tcpdump -D` and looking for the lowest numbered interface in the list that isn't a loopback interface.